# php,mysql, отправка данных

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, новичок в вебе. Есть форма для авторизации, при отправке данные идут в mysql, как сделать так чтобы при отправке перебрасывало на вторую страницу где уже другой контент и данные соответственно отправлялись в бд как и прежде? Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотри тут `form action`. http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/action.
Пример `<form action="Другая страница">`

Comment: сделал к там написано, переделал action перебрасывает на другую страницу, но теперь данные не записываются в бд. Что делать?

Comment: Как не заполняются ? это уже другой вопрос, вы в нужном `action` должны обработать данные в сервере и заполнить базу

Comment: код add.php            <?php
include_once("db.php");
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
         $username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['username'])));
         $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));
         $password = md5($_POST['password']);
         mysql_query(" 
                      INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) 
                      VALUE ('$username','$email','$password')
                     ");
         mysql_close();
    }     ?>

Comment: код dp.php <?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "mybd_user", "12345");
    $db = mysql_select_db("my-db");
    mysql_set_charset("utf-8");
    
    
    if(!$connection || !$db) {
        exit(mysql_error());
    } 


?>

Answer (score 2):

После того как в скрипте были получены данные и эти данные были занесены в базу данных, необходимо выполнить перенаправление на нужную страницу с помощью заголовка

```
header('Location: http://ваш_домен.ru/нужная_страница.php/');
exit;
```

Этот код должен быть размещен до любого другого вывода информации.

Comment: не судите строго, новичок в этом деле, но у меня есть 2 файла. add.php   в котором есть 3 формы(username,email,password) и кнопка submit. все обработано и работает, данные сохраняются. и есть db.php со стандартным подключением к бд. мне теперь нужно header('Location: http://ваш_домен.ru/нужная_страница.php/');
exit;       вначале add.php прописать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Прописать нужно в как я понимаю в файл add.php. Именно там у вас должны быть строки с запросом типа "INSERT INTO", Вот после этой строки нужно вставлять перенаправление.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: page.ext');
exit;
```

Вместо page.ext вставьте свое название перенаправляющей страницы, обязательно не забудьте выйти из скрипта, иначе он продолжит свое действие после закрытия